# How to show that $P\{t\leq t_1\}=1-e^{-ct_1}$

Tags: probability

In the following problem:

> If the space $S$ is a set of positive numbers, How to show that if
>   $P\{t_0 \leq t \leq t_0 + t_1 | t \geq t_0\} = P\{t \leq t_1\}$ for
>   all $t_0$ and $t_1$ then $P\{t\leq t_1\}=1-e^{-ct_1}$.

I don't get how he moves from:

$$ \frac{\int_{t_0}^{t_0 + t_1}{\alpha(t)\mathrm{d}t}}{\int_{t_0}^{+\infty}{\alpha(t)\mathrm{d}t}} = \int_{0}^{t_1}{\alpha(t)\mathrm{d}t}$$

to the following:
$$ \frac{\alpha(t_0)}{\int_{t_0}^{+\infty}{\alpha(t)\mathrm{d}t}} = \alpha(0).$$

Comment: I guess we assumed that the probability has a continuous distribution function. Take the derivative with respect to $t_1$ and take $t_1=0$.

Comment: Now if only Mina would say what $\alpha$ is supposed to be...

Comment: @Davide, *continuity* of a distribution function does not imply its differentiability.

Comment: @DidierPiau yes, you're right. I meant "differentiale", but I don't know why I wrote "continuous".

Comment: @Davide, understood. But in fact it is not necessary to assume that the distribution function is differentiable to get the result, not even that it is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint. Call $G(t_0)=P(T\geqslant t_0)$, then 
$$
P(t_0\leqslant T\leqslant t_0+t_1\mid T\geqslant t_0)=1-P(T\geqslant t_0+t_1\mid T\geqslant t_0)=1-G(t_0+t_1)/G(t_0),
$$
hence the hypothesis can be translated as $G(t_0+t_1)/G(t_1)=G(t_0)$. Now, what would be a nonincreasing function $G$ such that $G(t_0+t_1)=G(t_1)G(t_0)$ for every nonnegative $t_0$ and $t_1$?